# OpenMP Fortran location of function result

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran, intel-fortran

**EDIT**: I added some output and a link the code on github.

I try to write a finite difference function in Fortran using OpenMP, but the behavior seems different between ifort (15.0.1 20141023) and gfortran (4.8.5 20150623). The code works well in sequential.

Indeed, the result of the function seems shared with gfortran and I don't really understand how it works with ifort.

The code below works well with gfortran (`-g -O3 -fopenmp`): all threads use the same location of `fd`, the result of my function.

But with ifort (`-g -O3 -traceback -heap-arrays`), it seems that it's not the case.

I don't know very well OpenMP specifications, I didn't find something related to the attribute of the function's result.

Finally, valgrind run well with gfortran but return a lot of errors with ifort

Did I missed something?

```
program test 

!$ use OMP_lib
use iso_fortran_env
implicit none


integer :: x,y
integer,parameter :: Nbx = 1000, Nby = 1000
real(real64), dimension(Nbx,Nby) :: trucAD=0, trucD=0
real(real64) :: dx=1

!$OMP PARALLEL 

!$OMP DO
do y=1,Nby
do x=1,Nbx
    trucAD(x,y) = x*dx
enddo
enddo
!$OMP END DO

trucD = dfonc2dxd(trucAD,Nbx,Nby,dx)

!$OMP SINGLE

write(*,*) 'Reference result =====>    ', Nbx*Nby*dx
write(*,*) 'Result per threads:'
!$OMP END SINGLE


!$OMP CRITICAL
!$ write(*,*) '#t: ',omp_get_thread_num(), 'test: ', sum(trucD)
!$OMP END CRITICAL


!$OMP END PARALLEL
contains


function dfonc2dxd(foncad,DimX, DimY,da) result(fd)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: DimX, DimY
        real(real64), dimension(DimX,DimY) :: fd
        real(real64), dimension(DimX,DimY), intent(in) :: foncad
        real(real64),intent(in) :: da
        integer :: qq , ii , xx
real(real64), dimension(11,5), parameter :: coef_diff5dc = reshape((/&
-2.391602219538d0,  5.832490322294d0, -7.650218001181d0, 7.907810563576d0, -5.922599052629d0,  3.071037015445d0,& 
-1.014956769726d0,  0.170022256519d0,  0.002819958377d0,-0.004791009708d0, -0.000013063429d0,&

-0.180022054228d0, -1.237550583044d0,  2.484731692990d0,-1.810320814061d0,  1.112990048440d0, -0.481086916514d0,& 
 0.126598690230d0, -0.015510730165d0,  0.000021609059d0, 0.000156447570d0, -0.000007390277d0,&

 0.057982271137d0, -0.536135360383d0, -0.264089548965d0, 0.917445877604d0, -0.169688364841d0, -0.029716326170d0,&
 0.029681617641d0, -0.005222483773d0, -0.000118806260d0,-0.000118806260d0, -0.000020069730d0,&

-0.013277273810d0,  0.115976072920d0, -0.617479187931d0,-0.274113948204d0,  1.086208764653d0, -0.402951626982d0,&
 0.131066986242d0, -0.028154858354d0,  0.002596328316d0, 0.000128743150d0,  0.000000000000d0,&

 0.016756572303d0, -0.117478455239d0,  0.411034935097d0,-1.130286765151d0,  0.341435872099d0,  0.556396830543d0,&
-0.082525734207d0,  0.003565834658d0,  0.001173034777d0,-0.000071772607d0, -0.000000352273d0 /)               &
 ,shape(coef_diff5dc),order=(/1,2/))
real(real64),dimension(5),parameter::coef_diff=(/0.872756993962667d0,-0.286511173973333d0,0.09032000128000002d0,&
                                                 -0.020779405824000d0,0.0024845946880000d0/)
        real(real64) :: unsda
        unsda = 1.0d0/da

!$OMP SINGLE
!$ write(*,*) 'Location of fd for every threads'
!$OMP END SINGLE

!$ write(*,*) omp_get_thread_num(), loc(fd)
!$OMP BARRIER

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC)
do qq = 1, DimY

!calcul des points centrés
        do ii=6, DimX-5
                fd(ii,qq) = 0
                do xx=1, 5
                      fd(ii,qq) = fd(ii,qq) + coef_diff(xx)*(foncad(ii+xx,qq) - foncad(ii-xx,qq))
                enddo
                fd(ii,qq) = unsda * fd(ii,qq) 
        enddo

! calcul des points décentrés
       do ii=1,5  !points avant
               fd(ii,qq) = 0 
               do xx=1, 11
                       fd(ii,qq) = fd(ii,qq) + coef_diff5dc(xx,ii)*foncad(xx,qq)        
               enddo
               fd(ii,qq) = unsda*fd(ii,qq) 
       enddo
       do ii = DimX, DimX-4,-1   !points arriere
               fd(ii,qq) = 0
               do xx=1, 11
                        fd(ii,qq) = fd(ii,qq) - coef_diff5dc(xx,DimX-ii+1)*foncad(DimX-xx+1,qq)
                enddo
                fd(ii,qq) = unsda * fd(ii,qq) 
        enddo
    enddo
    !$OMP END DO
    end function dfonc2dxd


    end program test
```

When I use gfortran, I obtain:

```
Location of result fd, for every threads
       4              6304000
       3              6304000
       0              6304000
       2              6304000
       1              6304000
 Reference=====>       1000000.0000000000     
 Result per threads:
 #t:            4 test:    1000000.0000000000     
 #t:            2 test:    1000000.0000000000     
 #t:            3 test:    1000000.0000000000     
 #t:            1 test:    1000000.0000000000     
 #t:            0 test:    1000000.0000000000
```

All threads works on the same result in fortran function and the result seems correct. No valgrind warning.

When I try with ifort:

```
Location of result fd, for every threads
       0        47402661998608
       3        47402629984272
       2        47402645991440
       1        47402637987856
       4        47402653995024
 Reference=====>       1000000.00000000     
 Result per threads:
```

And it's locked. Result don't have the same location for every threads.
With valgrind, I get a huge log of errors. I putted it on github:
https://github.com/Hilid/test_OMP/blob/master/logval.txt

Comment: Welcome. Which results do you get? Which exact errors do you get with ifort and valgrind? Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. We need to understand how to test your code and what to expect.

Comment: Sorry, i forget it in my post,  I used the fopenmp option for ifort compilation.

Comment: I edited my post with some output and a link to github with the code and the valgrind output for the ifort case.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to achieve you're going about this the wrong way. Rather look at the workshare directive (e.g. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_13.1.0/com.ibm.xlf131.aix.doc/proguide/workshared.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `loc(fd)` is useful in any way. It can be a temporary variable anywhere in the memory (probably stack) or with some return-value optimization it can be the actual variable it is being assigned to. But only if it is being assigned to a variable. I don't think OpenMP changes much in this.

This code gives me a suspicion of a race condition, aren't multiple threads writing to the same shared variable?

```
!$OMP PARALLEL 
...
trucD = dfonc2dxd(trucAD,Nbx,Nby,dx)
```

Comment: You are right. So i can't use a function inside a parallel region to compute my derivation and store it like this?

Comment: You can use a subroutine.

Comment: Ok, I will use subroutine instead. Thinks for the help.